# Connecting Google Colaboratory Notebook to the local system (which is a remote system to my system)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, google-colaboratory, remote-server

I want to connect to my local system in Google Colaboratory notebook, and I have redirected to [this page](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html) as there explained the instructions for doing such a thing. However, the local system that I've been always working with and am trying to connect my Google Colaboratory notebook to it is actually a remote Linux-based machine.

Before when I wanted to start Jupyter notebook on my remote machine I ran this command on the remote machine that I was connected to through ssh:

```
$ jupyter notebook --no-browser --port=8889
```

Then in my own machine, I ran this command to work with the jupyter:

```
$ ssh -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 [username]@[remote_address]
```

However, now that the situation is different, even though I followed the given instructions in the link I still cannot connect Google Colaboratory notebook to the remote machine.

I tried to apply the usual procedure I do for tunneling to the remote machine, i.e I changed the port number to 8889 and ran that tunneling command in my system and in my Colab notebook which was opened with the browser in my system (not the remote) I entered the URL I was given as a token. I once changed 8889 in the URL to 8888 (something I had always been doing for opening running jupyter notebook on the remote machine, in my system), and another time I didn't change the port number. But, neither one worked.

I was wondering if anyone here knows what is the way for doing such a thing. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Thanks!